# homeomorphic topology of quotient space of $S^1$

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

I got stuck on the problem about quotient space from General Topology of Stephen Williard. Here is the problem:

> > Let $\sim$ be the equivalence relation $x \sim y$ iff $x$ and $y$ are diametrically opposite, on $S^1$. Which topology is the quotient space $S^1/\sim$ homeomorphic to?

I tried to build a continuous function $S^1$ such that 2 points which are diametrically have the same images, but I couldn't find it. For each point in $S^1$, we can write it as $(\cos(\phi), \sin(\phi))$, then what is the function which satisfies the previous requirement. Can anyone help me with this? I really appreciate.

Comment: What does diametrically opposite mean?

Comment: Have you seen projective spaces? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_space

Comment: Hint:  Consider the map $f:S^1\rightarrow S^1$ (thinking of $S^1\subseteq \mathbb{C}$) with $f(z) = z^2$.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan: Oh, I haven't heard about that space in topology. Let me check, thanks a lot

Comment: @JasonDeVito: So I guess the function f is $f((\cos x, \sin x)) = (\cos 2x, \sin 2x)$ in your case, right? I remembered that I tried to use that function when working on the exercise, but it seems not to transform 2 diametrically opposite points into one point. Am I missing something?

Comment: @leducquang:  Yes, your description of $f$ is the same as mine, but it's harder to see that it transforms diametrically opposed points to the same point.  In your notation, you need to check that $f(\cos (x + \pi), \sin(x+\pi)) = f(\cos x, \sin x)$, whereas in mine, you need to check that $f(-z) = f(z)$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: ha, I see your point now. Thanks so much for your clarification. I think I got it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a rubber band; that’s your $S^1$. Now fold it into a figure eight: 8. Finally, fold the $8$ about its horizontal midline to get a double circle. Thus, you’ve gone from **O** to **8** to doubled **o**. Check that this brings diametrically opposite points of the original **O** together: they’re simply on different copies of the **o**.

Comment: Wow, impressive. But I think we need to prove it clearly by a quotient map, right? Can you show what the function is for the transformation that you did?

Comment: @leducquang: You’re basically going around the circle twice as fast: the point whose polar coordinates are $\langle 1,\theta\rangle$ gets sent to the point whose polar coordinates are $\langle 1,2\theta\rangle$.

Comment: Oh, I see it now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @leducquang: You’re welcome!

Answer (score -1):

The space you will get is $\mathbb{RP}^1$, the one dimensional real projective space which is by definition of all lines through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^2$.